# react-native fetching an access/refresh token from spotify API

Tags: ios, react-native, fetch, spotify

I am using react-native (and by nature using the built in [fetch](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html) method. I have the following code that posts to spotify and is supposed to return a token, instead of a token I am receiving an error.

code:

```
  var btoa = require('base-64');      
  var authOptions = {
    method : 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      code: resCode,
      redirect_uri: 'myapp://foo',
      grant_type: 'authorization_code'
    }),
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa.encode(secrets.id + ':' + secrets.secret)
    },
    json: true
  };
  fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', authOptions).then(
    (res) => console.log(res)
  );
```

error I am receiving:

```
Response {_bodyInit: "{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_descripti…redentials, authorization_code or refresh_token"}", _bodyText: "{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_descripti…redentials, authorization_code or refresh_token"}", type: "default", url: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", status: 400…}
```

Comment: Are you sure the code `resCode` you're posting is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a `json` string in the post body, however according to the documentation you have to send parameters. Also if you look at the example curl request you can see how it's done:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic ZjM...zE=" -d grant_type=authorization_code -d code=MQCbtKe...44KN -d redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.foo.com%2Fauth https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
```

It's not `json`. Try sending the body as `FormData`.

Comment: Do you know how can I edit my usage of fetch to send parameters vs. the json string?

Comment: I think you can do `var data = new FormData(); data.append('code', resCode);` and do the same with the remaining parameters. According to the documentation you can simply pass the FormData as the body: `body: data` in your request.